# python re.sub not replacing all the occurance of string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I'm not getting the desire output, re.sub is only replacing the last occurance using python regular expression, please explain me what i"m doing wrong

```
srr = "http://www.google.com/#image-1CCCC| http://www.google.com/#image-1VVDD| http://www.google.com/#image-123|  http://www.google.com/#image-123| http://www.google.com/#image-1CE005XG03"
re.sub("http://.*[#]", "", srr)
'image-1CE005XG03'
```

**Desire output without http://www.google.com/#image from the above string.**

```
image-1CCCC|image-1VVDD|image-123|image-1CE005XG03
```

Comment: Use `re.sub("http://.*?#", "", srr)` or better ``re.sub("http://[^#]*#", "", srr)``

Comment: Include `?` in your pattern `re.sub("http://.*?[#]", "", srr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here, rather than trying to do a replacement to remove the portions you don't want:

```py
src = "http://www.google.com/#image-1CCCC| http://www.google.com/#image-1VVDD| http://www.google.com/#image-123|  http://www.google.com/#image-123| http://www.google.com/#image-1CE005XG03"
matches = re.findall(r'https?://www\.\S+#([^|\s]+)', src)
output = '|'.join(matches)
print(output)  # image-1CCCC|image-1VVDD|image-123|image-123|image-1CE005XG03
```

Note that if you want to be more specific and match only Google URLs, you may use the following pattern instead:

```regex
https?://www\.google\.\S+#([^|\s]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> "|".join(re.findall(r'#([^|\s]+)', srr))
'image-1CCCC|image-1VVDD|image-123|image-123|image-1CE005XG03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
"|".join(i.split("#")[-1] for i in srr.split("|"))
```

---

```
image-1CCCC|image-1VVDD|image-123|image-123|image-1CE005XG03
```

Answer (score 0):

Using correct regex in `re.sub` as suggested in comment above:

```sh
import re

srr = "http://www.google.com/#image-1CCCC| http://www.google.com/#image-1VVDD| http://www.google.com/#image-123|  http://www.google.com/#image-123| http://www.google.com/#image-1CE005XG03"
print (re.sub(r"\s*https?://[^#\s]*#", "", srr))
```

**Output:**

```sh
image-1CCCC|image-1VVDD|image-123|image-123|image-1CE005XG03
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `https?`: Match `http` or `https`
- `://`: Match `://`
- `[^#\s]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `#` and whitespace
- `#`: Match a `#`